# Python Tkinter: bind complex events

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

For example, I want to print something in the console when I hold the mouse left click and 's' (lower case) key at the same time. How can I do this? Is this possible?

```py
    def foo(event):
        print('foo')
    window = Tk()
    window.bind('what is the event here', foo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the state in the event that's passed to the call back.

```
from tkinter import *


def foo(event):
    if event.state & (1 << 8):
        print('foo')


window = Tk()
window.bind('<Key-s>', foo)


window.mainloop()
```